# Time for row extraction in np.array

Tags: python, numpy, row, extract, timeit

When optimizing part of a code in python I observed the following :

```
x = np.random.randn(100, 20)
a = np.arange(20)
%timeit x
```

23 nano sec

```
%timeit x[a]
```

1.7 micro sec

While x[a] is a smaller array, it takes more time to reach. Do you please know what can cause this ? Similar results are observed if instead of x, I ask for x.T.dot(x) and x[a].T.dot(x[a]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your headline testcase is flawed, `x` being just a reference, your observation stands if less extreme for

```
>>> timeit(lambda: x[a], number=1000000)
1.8212362979538739
>>> timeit(lambda: x.copy(), number=1000000)
1.2187692462466657
```

What we are seeing here is the cost of advanced indexing. "Conventional" slice indexing costs significantly less but still has an overhead:

```
>>> np.all(x[:20] == x[a])
True
>>> timeit(lambda: x[:20].copy(), number=1000000)
0.7956113098189235
```

Answer (score 2):

`%timeit x` times how long it takes to do nothing with `x`. It's pretty easy to do nothing.

`%timeit x[a]` times how long it takes to actually do a thing with `x`, that thing being dynamically work out what the indexing operation means and then copy the 20 specified rows into a new array. Doing things is a lot harder than doing nothing.